# answer code block juniper table routage

Tags: routing, networking, juniper, juniper-junos

want some one expert juniper help me for this question

user@router> show route 192.168.100.2 inet.O: 15 destinations, 17 routes (15 active, 0 holddown, 0 hidden) Limit/Threshold: 1048576/1048576 destinations

= Active Route, - = Last Active, * = Both 192.168.100.2/32 *[OSPF/1O] 00:14:29, metric 1 > to 172.16.1.6 via ge-0/0/1.0 [BGP/170] 00:06:49, localpref 100 AS path: 65102 I, validation state: unverified > to 172.16.1.6 via ge-0/0/1.0 Referring to the exhibit, which statement is correct?
A. The BGP path is the only active route. B. The BGP route is preferred over the OSPF route. C. The OSPF path is the only active route.
D. / Traffic is load-balanced across two routes.

so please what is the answer correct !! Thanks

Comment: Please don't just repost when your question has been closed as off topic.